# How to run inkview in installed flatpak inkscape

Tags: software-installation, inkscape, flatpak, image-viewers

I have installed the last version of [Inkscape via flatpak](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0/gnulinux/flatpak/dl/) in Xubuntu 16.04. and it runs smoothly. The problem is that I would like to use `inkview` as standard `.svg` viewer, but I do not find `inkview` in the installed flatpak :-\. That seems odd to me, because `inkview` came integrated with `inkscape` when I installed the package via *Package Manager*.

Is `inkview` available in the flatpak installation? How could I run it?

If not, how could I install `inkview` independently from `inkscape`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a tricky way by using special `--command=inkview` option:

```
flatpak run --command=inkview org.inkscape.Inkscape ~/drawing.svg
```

---

See details in the output of `flatpak run -?`:

> ```
> Usage:
>    flatpak run [OPTION...] APP [ARGUMENT…] - Run an app
>
> Application Options:
> ...
>      --command=COMMAND                       Command to run
> ...
> ```

Comment: It works! Thanks. Now I can delete the `dpkg` installation of `Inkscape`, I kept it only for the sake of `inkview` ´:-). Now, I cannot understand why I did not find the answer by googling it; It seems quite straightforward.   :-\